# Can I use the Python Ros bag API without making a workspace?

Tags: python, rosbag, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using roscpp, but I'd like to make a transferrable python script for working with bag files. However, the docs only tell me how to do it through a catkin workspace. Is there a way to import the necessary libraries without first making a workspace?

I'm referring to the error mentioned [in this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/12307/no-module-named-rosbag-error/)

The proposed solution was to change a manifest file. I'd like to be able to do this without going through a workspace so I can share the script with others.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258130/can-i-use-the-python-ros-bag-api-without-making-a-workspace?/) by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2017-03-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes, you can.

to avoid that error you have to make sure you have properly set the ROS path in your current terminal window, which is normally accomplished by doing:

```
source /opt/ros/ROSVERSION/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-03-29**:
Ah hah! I did this already, but I found that the problem is actually that I was trying to execute the python program through my Sublime editor. For anyone that might have had the same problem, I just needed to change the python build file to include the ros folders in PYTHONPATH and PATH.

**Comment by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on 2017-03-29**:
Your answer gave put me on the right track and is correct, thank you.